# Unsynchronized star buttons in chat

Tags: bug, chat

There seems to be a bug in the chat starring system. Basically when pressing the star button on the *top-starred-messages* list seems not to be updating the starred status on the actual message, and viceversa.

[Here's a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j6jfvx4Suts) I took to demonstrate it. Notice that when I click there's an animation triggered (a circle imploding into the cursor).

I'm using Google Chrome on Mac OS X Mountain Lion.

Comment: -1 video needs more freehand circles.

Comment: An older question exists: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139175/212576