# Starring post in starred list does not make star yellow on message

Tags: bug, chat, chat-stars

I have recently noticed that if one stars a message such as this one in the starred posts list:

[image]

That although you get the little number go up by one next to the message, the star next to the message does not go yellow, only in the list:

[image]

This however does not happen the other way round.

Comment: Does F5/refresh change that?

Comment: This area of chat (stars and pins) is generally funky. IIRC there should already be something similar around...

Comment: Is [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139175/when-starring-a-message-from-the-star-board-its-not-reflected-in-the-main-chat) the same bug?